# python websockets consumer and producer examples needed

Tags: python, websocket

http://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#consumer contains the following example:

```
async def consumer_handler(websocket, path):
    while True:
        message = await websocket.recv()
        await consumer(message)
```

and http://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#producer

```
async def producer_handler(websocket, path):
    while True:
        message = await producer()
        await websocket.send(message)
```

But there is no example for `consumer()` and `producer()` implementation or any explanation. Can somebody provide any simple example for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, `consumer_handler` listens for the messages from a websocket connection. It then passes the messages to a `consumer`. In its simplest form, a consumer can look like this:

```
async def consumer(message):
    # do something with the message
```

---

In the second example, `producer_handler` receives a message from a `producer` and sends it to the websocket connection. A producer can look like this:

```
async def producer():
    message = "Hello, World!"
    await asyncio.sleep(5) # sleep for 5 seconds before returning message
    return message
```

Comment: thank you! I haven't worked with `asyncio` lately and websockets in particular. So obvious :D